# Optimising IF-THEN-ELSE in trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I have a trigger which needs to make a match on a phone number, so far this works, but it seems rather not optimised:

```
IF NEW.caller LIKE '44%' THEN
    caller_tmp := SUBSTRING(NEW.caller FROM 3);
    IF caller_tmp ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN
        NEW.caller_name := (SELECT phonenumber_name FROM phonebook WHERE caller_tmp::BIGINT LIMIT 1);
    END IF;
ELSEIF NEW.caller LIKE '+44%' THEN
    caller_tmp := SUBSTRING(NEW.caller FROM 4);
    IF caller_tmp ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN
        NEW.caller_name := (SELECT phonenumber_name FROM phonebook WHERE caller_tmp::BIGINT LIMIT 1);
    END IF;
ELSEIF NEW.caller LIKE '0044%' THEN
    caller_tmp := SUBSTRING(NEW.caller FROM 5);
    IF caller_tmp ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN
        NEW.caller_name := (SELECT phonenumber_name FROM phonebook WHERE caller_tmp::BIGINT LIMIT 1);
    END IF;
END IF;
```

I need to check if the phone number is from the UK with either containing 44, +44 or 0044 in the front. If it does, I need to check if it's a valid integer, and then do my matching.

Could this be optimised for better perfomance?

Comment: `WHERE caller::BIGINT` is an invalid condition. You need a boolean expression there, not a number. Also that will fail miserably if you have more then one row in the `phonebook` table.

Comment: True, updated. Copy-pasted the wrong query I'm testing with.

Comment: Better optimized than this? Hardly (you will most likely run at least one pattern matching anyway). More readable/simple? Yes. F.ex. with `substring(caller from '^(?:|\+|00)44([0-9]+)$')` -- http://rextester.com/LSD80924

Comment: `caller_temp := regexp_replace(new.caller, '^00|\+', '')` seems to do the tricK

Comment: I like this caller_temp := regexp_replace(new.caller, '^00|\+', ''), but is there a way to check in one go if the new.caller contains either 44, +44 or 0044, and then do the regexp_replace? Because if the number is not a UK number I will not "have anything" to do with it.